# CKEditor ReadOnly with Enabled Toolbar Buttons

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, readonly

I am working in Rails project, setting a CKEditor instance to true for readOnly mode. That works well.

My next step is trying to enable in the toolbar a custom plugin button while keeping the textarea in readOnly mode.

I have found an example here:
https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8959
describing that in the definition of the plugin I can define if readOnly is available for setting.

As a result of this recommendation, in my code I have done this:

> ```
> editor.ui.add('normal_values', CKEDITOR.UI_MENUBUTTON, {
>   label: 'Reference Ranges',
>         modes: {wysiwyg: 1},
>         readOnly: 0,
>         icon: '<%= asset_path("icons/book-open.png") %>',
>         onMenu: function () {
>                 var active = {};
>                  for (var p in items)
>                   active[p] = CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF;
>
>                  return active;
>                 }
>             });
> ```

The property comes through when I debug in the browser
[Toolbar Object in Javascript Chrome Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjDKe.png)

but it still does not bring up the plugin.

I am not sure what else to try so any suggestions or help would be extremely helpful.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi. I'm also experiencing the same problem. I wonder if you could find the solution to your problem, and what would it be. I need the read-only mode with the ability to still use a few buttons. Thanks

Comment: Have you got the solution ? if yes than please post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This property readOnly:true shoud be set in "command" definition not in "button"

If command is a custom dialog

```
editor.addCommand( 'LockUI', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'lockUIDialog' ));
```

Just append property readOnly

```
var cmd=new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'lockUIDialog' );
    cmd.readOnly=true;
    editor.addCommand( 'LockUI', cmd );
```

Answer (score 0):

"When defining a command it is possible to mark it as valid for read-only, by setting the readOnly property of the command definition to 1 or true." - So you should try to set 1/true to readOnly property